# Ask about raw queries es on graphdb

Tags: graphdb

I'm query by SPARQL like this
PREFIX inst: http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/elasticsearch/instance#

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/elasticsearch#>
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/elasticsearch/instance#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    select ?entity {
    ?search a inst:test ;
            :query '''{
     {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : [ {
              "query_string" : {
                "query" : "Vie"
              }
            }]
          }
        }   
} 
      ''' ;
      :entities ?entity .
}
```

and the connector and data

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/elasticsearch#>
PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/elasticsearch/instance#>


INSERT DATA {
    inst:test :createConnector '''
{
  "elasticsearchNode": "localhost:9200",
  "types": [
    "http://test.com#Person"
  ],
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "age",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://test.com#age"
      ],
      "analyzed": false
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "learn",
      "propertyChain": [
        "http://test.com#learn"
      ],
      "fielddata": true
    }
  ]
}
''' .
}

Data

PREFIX test: <http://test.com#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

insert data {
    test:5 rdf:type test:Person;
           test:age 11112;
           test:learn "Vie" .
}
```

But i always get `Error 500`
Query evaluation error: Invalid json for raw query given.
I have tried many times but cant query by raw query ES.
How can i raw query es on graphdbb. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in documentation, that's why this error is thrown. I'll raise issue in GraphDB documentation. The provided example isn't valid JSON. Change query to:

```
  PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/elasticsearch#>
  PREFIX inst: <http://www.ontotext.com/connectors/elasticsearch/instance#>
  PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
        select ?entity {
        ?search a inst:test ;
                :query '''{
        "query" : {
              "bool" : {
                "should" : [ {
                  "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "Vie"
                  }
                }]
              }
            }   
    } 
          ''' ;
          :entities ?entity .
    }
```

Comment: What is this "ABC". This is not valid query. Can you give me example of your create connector query and loaded data.

Comment: @david backa, I've updated the answer. The problem is missed one part of the query in GraphDB documentation.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question